# Is it possible to apply Wagtail CMS to my existing Django project?

Tags: django, wagtail

I recently found [wagtail](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail), which is a very cool Django CMS library. I tried to use it following its documentation, but its installing documentation is based on starting-over Django project.

I'm using ReactJS for frontend and Django as API backend. I was wondering if it's possible for me to apply wagtail to my existing Django project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Documentation for integrating Wagtail into an existing Django project is here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/integrating_into_django.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. It let me access wagtail CMS on my existing Django app. However, I don't see my models on the CMS which are the models that I can see on my default Django admin. Are they not compatible each other?

Comment: No, the Wagtail admin backend is a separate thing from Django admin. The Modeladmin module is one option for making your Django models available within Wagtail admin, though: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html

Comment: You should use Wagtail's admin-pages to do "all Wagtail things."  Don't monkey around with them in the Django admin.  Be sure that your URL-patterns occur before any Wagtail patterns (and, that they are distinct from them).  Otherwise, "Wagtail's just a Django app," and it works quite well.  (I've also used Peregrine, a dedicated blog-app, simultaneously with Wagtail.)  The beauty of Django is that you have ... _choices._

Answer (score 2):

Yes Totally possible here is a guide on how to do specifically that.
[Integrate Wagtail into existing Django project](https://www.dothedev.com/blog/integrate-wagtail-into-existing-django-project-django-blog-app/#)

You will have a wagtail backend to manage the content of say your blog page and the existing django admin will stay the same. This is kind of helping to managing the content easily which is essentially what CMS is for.

This blogpost is for managing the backend with wagtail and frontend is HTML(Jinja)/css you would have to look into how it will be relative for you using ReactJS but if you want one app(this blog app) to be served just using HTML and css and not in react workflow this can work as it is for you.